# Please flag spam!

Tags: discussion, spamming, flagging

We've had a rash of spam today.  It's not lasted long, but the spammers have been diligent and we've had to destroy a dozen or more posts and three separate accounts (the 'community' bumps on the front page are all spam deletions).

If you see spam happening, please remember to flag it as such.  Community moderators like Kortuk, Mark, and myself will react quickly to such flags, and they're also visible to the Stack Exchange Inc. team.  Plus, with a few spam flags from the community, the post is deleted, a rep penalty subtracted (though this usually simply reduces the authors' rep to 1) and a temporary ban imposed on the spammer.

As a warning, don't click on the links even if you want to buy a soccer jersey: [Google Safe Search's report](http://google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=AS:32097) for the hosting network says:

> #### What happened when Google visited sites hosted on this network?
>
> Of the 8194 site(s) we tested on this network over the past 90 days, 247 site(s), including, for example, (redacted), served content that resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent.
>
> The last time Google tested a site on this network was on 2012-06-04, and the last time suspicious content was found was on 2012-06-04.
>
> #### Has this network hosted sites acting as intermediaries for further malware distribution?
>
> Over the past 90 days, we found 9 site(s) on this network, including, for example, (redacted), that appeared to function as intermediaries for the infection of 19 other site(s) including, for example, (redacted).
>
> #### Has this network hosted sites that have distributed malware?
>
> Yes, this network has hosted sites that have distributed malicious software in the past 90 days. We found 51 site(s), including, for example, (redacted), that infected 159 other site(s), including, for example, (redacted).

Answer (score 3):

I flagged them immediately, several ones. I understand that this will generate a lot of flags, I won't be the only one, but then it's clear to the mods that this is a real problem, which should be stopped as soon as possible. Here spammer seems to have stopped posting after a dozen of posts, but I they persist they could go on for hundreds of posts, render the Top Questions list useless.

I appreciate that mods react quickly to this. I think it's necessary to signal to the spammers that what they do is useless. Flag, and do it immediately when you see spam.

Answer (score 2):

for a fun time msg ♦Kevin at [www.redlightdistrict.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/895/ee-ask-a-moderator)

Comment: For some reason I cant use the destroy command on those users that have more then 500 rep, but this is the perfect chance to get tyblu once and for all!

Answer (score 0):

From my years of presence at various Stack Exchange sites I'd say one thing: flag it, but don't make it a big deal.

Yes, spammers are stubborn, they think their "promotion efforts" are cute and welcome and we have to just live with that.

Stack Exchange has very good tools for patrolling and flagging spam including automatic deletion of stuff with enough spam votes. Use the tools without any doubt and don't let those guys put you in bad mood.

Comment: They *know* that their "promotion efforts" aren't cute, nor welcome, that's exactly the reason why they're so aggressive.