# CAPTCHA being too aggressive

Tags: support

I feel something is wrong with CAPTCHA on Electronics SE and Electronics Meta. For the last several days I ask something like no more than one question per day and I'm shown CAPTCHA almost every time.

Recently I asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33369/3552) and was shown CAPTCHA although I haven't asked or edited anything before that. Then I went here and posted [this answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/3552) and again was shown CAPTCHA - I haven't done anything else on this Meta today.

When I tried to post this (the current) question I also was asked to enter CAPTCHA although no more than ten minutes passed between I posted the answer and I didn't do anything else in between.

So I feel CAPTCHA is too aggressive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you a human? (No lying!)

Comment: @W5VO: No lying on the Internet? That's ridiculous.

Comment: @W5VO, sounds like he is avoiding the human question, since robots can lie this is pretty much proof he is not a human.

Comment: The system seems to be very sensitive to inactivity and requests a Captcha if you have been inactive immediately prior to posting. Olin has [asked this before](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1035/2234) (see his first point - and my comment).

Comment: Did you copy and paste a block of text from another editor? If you suddenly have 500 more characters in your text it might think you're a bot.

Comment: @stevenvh: I certainly pasted in links, but they are rather short. I typed in all the text by hand.

Comment: I agree the captcha is triggered too easily if you're already logged in, and it can be very hard to read for a mere human.  I think the SE folks need to lighten up a bit.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/955/do-we-really-need-a-captcha-for-established-users

Comment: Is this still giving you trouble?

Comment: @Anna Lear: I've asked this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34074/whats-the-need-for-conductive-bridges-between-the-regions-of-a-smart-card-conta recently - no CAPTCHA was shown.